# Vue.js router transition slide

Tags: html, css, vue.js, transition

I have some problem

I want to look like an application on the web.

but i use vue.js transition look like this

[image: problem image]

Automatically reduce size, increase size and repeat.

This is code

```
<transition name="slide">
    <router-view class="main" v-cloak/>
</transition>


.slide-enter, {
  opacity: 0;

}
.slide-leave-active, .slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

How to fix this problem? and happy new year!!! (__)

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem

This was a problem with the order.

Fixed the Z-index value for the incoming element

```
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-enter-to, .slide-fade-enter-active{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: -100;

}
```